# MVC Unity DI Setter Method Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have been reading for a couple of days about Unity in MVC, and I've been trying to get this to work - hoping you guys can help.

I've set up Unity in the way described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/07/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-app-using-unity-2-0.aspx) which, from extensive googling, seems common enough.  I can probably confirm that this setup is working, since on my Home Controller I can get this DI to work nicely:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Dependency]
    public IRepository repo { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string message = repo.GetMessage();

        ViewData["OUT"] = message;

        return View();
    }
}
```

However, I have a class ("Contact") which for various reasons also needs access to repository methods, hence the coupling, and the requirement for DI.  So within the class I have a [Dependency] property just as above.  So for example I have the following code:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    [Dependency]
    public IRepository repo { get; set; }

    public string CoupledProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return repo.GetCoupledProperty();
        }
    }
```

So then if I attempt to retrieve an already existing Contact object on the Home Controller, e.g.:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Dependency]
    public IRepository repo { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Contact contact = repo.GetContact(1);
        string message = contact.CoupledProperty;

        ViewData["OUT"] = message;

        return View();
    }
}
```

I get an object not instantiated error highlighting the line of the code on the Contact class where the CoupledProperty attempts to access the repository.  And of course, swapping out the Dependency property in the Contact class for a hard coded repository object works properly.

Can anyone see what is going wrong here?

Cheers,

Tim.

EDIT:

The GetContact(int) method in the repository is:

```
public Contact GetContact(int id)
{
    return db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactID == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the `GetContact(int)` method look like in your repository implementation? Does it use Unity to produce the contact? I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: Yes.  The method retrieves the details from a database table.  Added the code above.  So that's the issue, eh?  I need to somehow use Unity to produce all my objects with dependencies...?

Comment: Yes, either to produce them, or to populate their dependencies after they are produced. But if the objects coming out of your repositories have dependencies, this is a code smell that tells me you're not separating concerns well enough. Why does each Contact need to have a repository on it? Shouldn't this functionality go on another class? If you'll update your question with more details about what you're trying to accomplish, I'll update my answer with some suggestions on how better to organize your code to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks alot, mate.  It's just a validation method on the repository that checks, e.g., whether there is already a Contact object with same name, email address, etc, to prevent duplication.  So following teh NerdDinner tutorial, I've exposed an "IsValid" bool on the class which runs a "GetRuleViolations()" method - I call the repo from there.  I toyed with a separate "Validator" class to pass the Contact object to, but it seemed unduly convoluted.  However, I remain open to alternatives; as is probably obvious, I am relatively inexperienced, so very open to advice and suggestion!  Cheers.

Comment: I'd personally go with using a separate "Validator" service class. It helps with "separation of concerns." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: Yeah, I've got that pattern working well enough, and will go with it.  Thanks again for your help!  Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it with DependencyResolver, if thats the resolver you are using.

```
repo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write some unit tests alongside all this code to continuously test and validate the code you have written. Besides StriplingWarrior's suggestion, I would also recommend you to check your DI Container wireup.